# How do I strip quotes out of a list of strings?

Tags: python, list, split

Hello guys I am having some issue trying to split my list into multiple element, my problem is the following:
I have a list like that:

```
list1 = ['"22.23.24.25"']
```

(basically this list should represent an IP address but never mind)
the problem is that I want to delete the quotation mark currently into my list, ideally my list would like:

```
list1 = ['22.23.24.25']
```

I really don't know how to do it since I am a beginner in python so it would be great if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is use the  [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method twice, to ensure that all types of the quotations are removed.

```
list1 = ['"22.23.24.25"', "'11.22.33.44'"]

list1 = [x.replace('"', '').replace("'", '') for x in list1]

print(list1)
['22.23.24.25', '11.22.33.44']
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing in all elements in a list:

```
a=[i.replace("\"","") for i in list1]
```

result:

```
['22.23.24.25']
```

this iterates over all elements in list1, performs an action on each and puts them into new list

Answer (score 2):

Just for the collection:

```
list1 = ['"22.23.24.25"', "'11.22.33.44'", "11.22.33.44"]

new_list = "\n".join(list1).replace("\"","").replace("'","").split("\n")

print(new_list) # ['22.23.24.25', '11.22.33.44', '11.22.33.44']
```

1. Join the array in one long string.
2. Remove all quotes from the string.
3. Split the sting back into an array.

This is a quite common technique. And probably it works faster than a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['"22.23.24.25"']
for i in range(len(list1)):
    x=list1[i].replace("\"","")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1=['"10.40.30.40.50"']
for x in l1:
    s=str(l1[0])
    for n in s:
        value=s[1:len(s)-1]
print(value)
```

Just a another method.

Comment: your solution will work only for string with quotation inside and the OP want to get a list at the end.